# accidentally deleted windows power settings by powercfg /deletesetting

Tags: windows-10, power-management

I accidentally deleted Windows power settings by `powercfg /deletesetting`, and now I can not restore it to default.

I tried restoring it from 
*Control Panel > Hardware and Sound > Power Options > Edit Plan Settings* and 
by the command `powercfg –restoredefaultschemes`, but none works!

Comment: See this page....https://winaero.com/blog/restore-default-power-plans-windows-10/

Comment: What errors are you having? See also [this article](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/43774-reset-restore-power-plans-default-settings-windows-10-a.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my computer, I delete one of power setting using your way, then I restore it with the following method：

In the registry, power setting are stored as below:

Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Power\PowerSettings
[image]

**And**

Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Control\Power\PowerSettings
[image]

1. We find a computer with Windows 10.
2. Locate at Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Power\PowerSettings and Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Control\Power\PowerSettings, then right click **PowerSettings**->**export** the registry file.
3. Copy the two exported registry files to the computer that we need to restore power settings.
4. Double-click the two copied registry files, then import the power settings.
5. Restart the computer.
6. View if we restore the power settings in control panel.

Comment: thanks i use the same way and its work correctly! but install same version of windows on Virtual machine and make a backup from power settings registry keys and import it on my windows registry.

Comment: You are welcome.I am so glad our issue is resolved.